# Remove and replace site collection admin powershell

Tags: powershell, site-collection, administration

I would like to remove user x from all site collections and replace with user y using powershell.  Does anyone have a script that works?  Google hasn't been helpful this time :-(

Comment: is it primary or secondary site collection admin?

Comment: I think Primary

Comment: then it is easy for on prem

Answer (score 1):

It would be a 2 step process, this is for SPO, but could be adapted for on prem easily enough.

```
$sites = get-sposite -limit All 

#process sites
foreach($site in $sites){
    Set-SPOUser -LoginName "user.1@domain.com" -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $false -Site $site.Url
    Set-SPOUser -LoginName "user.2@domain.com" -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $true -Site $site.Url
}
```

For on prem, it would look something like (not tested, no on prem instance to verify against)

```
$sites = get-spsite -limit All 

    #process sites
    foreach($site in $sites){
        Set-SPUser -Identity "domain\user1" -IsSiteCollectionAdmin:$false -Web $site.RootWeb.Url # colon is necessary
        Set-SPUser -Identity "domain\user2" -IsSiteCollectionAdmin:$true -Web $site.RootWeb.Url 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the new primary admin, it will remove the old.

```
 Write-Host -Foregroundcolor green "- Changing the site collection administrators"
    $site = Get-SPSite | ?{$_.Url -like "*sites/tempSite*"}
    If ($site -ne $null)
    {
        Set-SPSite -Identity $site.Url -OwnerAlias "DOMAIN\farmacc" -SecondaryOwnerAlias "DOMAIN\svcacc" 
        Write-Host -Foregroundcolor white "- Site Collection Administrators for '$site' is changed."
    }
```

I haven't tested but it will work.
[Changing Site Collection Administrators using PowerShell](http://www.keremozen.com/2012/10/24/changing-site-collection-administrators-using-powershell/)